# getPageTitle() does not override method from FragmentPagerAdapter()

Tags: java, android, fragmentpageradapter, android-pageradapter

I am trying to create swiping tabs with `FragmentPagerAdapter` like in [this example](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter). The problem is when i try to override `getPageTitle()` i get an error saying `Method does not override method from its superclass. How can i fix this?

This is what the adapter looks like:

```
public class AdapterMain extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
//The titles of each tab
private static final String[] TAB_TITLES = new String[]{"Fragment 1", "Fragment 2"};

/**
 * Default constructor
 * @param fragmentManager
 */
public AdapterMain(FragmentManager fragmentManager){
    super(fragmentManager);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position){
    switch (position){
        default:
            Log.wtf("AdapterMain", "Fragment not found! Crashing!");
            return null;

        case 0:
            return new FragmentA();

        case 1:
            return new FragmentB();
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount(){
    return TAB_TITLES.length;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
    return TAB_TITLES[position];
}
```

}

Comment: That certainly looks OK. What is the fully-qualified class name of `FragmentPagerAdapter` that you are using? IOW, what is the `import` statement for it?

Comment: I am using `android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter`

Comment: OK, so it's not that you are pulling in something else accidentally named the same... What version of `support-v4` are you using to get this from?

Comment: I am using `com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0`

Comment: Well, the sources for `support-v4:23.4.0` certainly show that method on `PagerAdapter` (from which `FragmentPagerAdapter` inherits). So, other than the obligatory "clean your project" suggestion, I am out of ideas -- sorry!

Comment: Alright well that didn't work but thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out i had an older or corrupted `android-support-v4.jar` under my `app/libs` folder. Once i deleted this `.jar` file, everything worked as expected.